# Async storage data load time

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am using Asyncstorage to store user data like:

```
try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(prod_id, '1').then(()=>{
        alert('Added to Cart');
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

but when I add it to onPress action it takes long time to save data and then my alert is called. Am I doing something wrong? Please I need help!

Comment: Asyncstorage.setItem is an async function so first, it will store the data then returns a promise. Till promise is resolved the function will wait.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "it takes long time", AsyncStorage is not quick. It is normal to have a certain delay

Comment: I am getting the length of key for the count when my app loads. But 4 out of 10 times it takes 5-8 mins aprox to load the data till then I can only see the  `<ActivityIndicator/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing two ways of handling the promises in JS.

1. Using Async await

```
async function SetItem(){
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(prod_id, '1')
    alert('Added to Cart');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

2. with then and catch

```
function SetItem(){
  return AsyncStorage.setItem(prod_id, '1')
  .then(()=>{
    alert('Added to Cart');
  }).catch((error)=> {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

calling this method

```
this.SetItem().then(()=>{
 console.log("value is set");
})
```